# How to perform async validation with debounce using ngx-formly?

Tags: angular, ngx-formly

I tried the following in my form config:

```
  fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
    {
      key: 'text',
      type: 'input',
      modelOptions: {
        debounce: {
          default: 2000,
        },
      },
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Debounce',
      },
      validators: ["test"]
    },
  ];
```

and the following `FormlyConfig` definition:

```
{
      validationMessages: [
        {
          name: 'test',
          message: "The value cannot be X",
        },
      ],
      validators: [
        {
          name: "test",
          validation: ((control: FormControl) => {
            return !!control.value || control.value === "X" ? null :  {test: true};
          })
        }
      ]
    }
```

What I observe, is that the validator is run instantly, regardless of the specified debounce.

Additionally, the model is updated with a debounce, while the angular form is updated instantly.

Is this a bug or the expected behavior? How do you debounce validation using ngx-formly?

Here's a stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-knzoth?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved as follows:

```
validation: (control: FormControl): ValidationErrors => {
  if (!control.value) {
    return of(null);
  }

  return control.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(control.value),
    debounceTime(500),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap(value => value === "X" ? null :  {test: true}),
    first()
  );
}
```